# Emberjs, inside Controller call this.transitionToRoute('index');

Tags: ember.js

```
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      console.log('Error occured!');
      this.transitionToRoute('main');
    },
```

Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionToRoute is not a function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.transitionToRoute('index')`?  What route are you trying to get to? Main or Index?